# Joomla creating pages dynamically

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am quite new to joomla. But not to HTML nor to PHP.

Now I want my users to be able to see information about eachother. because of this I wish to create a page (article) for each of them.

Now this page (article) is ofcourse going to be generated through PHP (collecting data from my user database) and is then displayed.

now to my question:

This site(article) should not display in the menu, nor should it display in a module it should actually be hidden unless someone either search for the user or clicks the user name. So how do I redirect and create a "Hidden" page in joomla?

Comment: I would guess that you need to create some sort of module/plugin and component combo, but it's not as easy as inserting plain php because you have to comply with joomla's architecture. You could start by looking at the developer's documents (http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) and once you have figured out what you need, you could use one of those component creators out there in order to get you started.

Comment: @mattosmat Thanks for the link maybe its just me but all of this seems VERY confusing.. :S

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying.  Why wouldn't you just make a page for each user in say an article or a contact form and make it available via search?  Where are they clicking the links from?

In joomla you don't really "use php" to make content, Joomla uses the php and you just make the content using an editor. To link to a user the basic options are to have the user be the author of an article, you could I guess have their name be the title, use a user profile or use the contact creator and make a contact for each user.

Comment: @Elin because the page will display more or less the same information for each user like the following:
Name: Marc
Last name: Rasmussen:
City: xxxx

ect ect ect. and at thend of the page i will use the google map api to locate them! so the site has to be created dynamicly according to what user is selected.

Comment: WHy don't you just use a profile and use the feature that lets you link a user to a contact record and then use com_contact. Yu can make a simple layout for embedding the maps even.   Not self promoting but this shows a contact form using the profile plugin. 
http://officialjoomlabook.com/school25/staff-directory/2-jane-smith